# getTag Getting Wrong Tag In ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with an on/off button for each item.

When it loads, all the users are off. I press user1, it turns on and sets the tag to "on". When I scroll down, user7 is turned on. In my log cat I can see that user7 is getting the tag from user1. Scrolling up and down seems to continue this pattern of views collecting the wrong tag.

I had a problem with listview recycling before, but it was solved by just making sure I set everything properly in getView.

Unfortunately, after hours and hours of troubleshooting / trial and error, I have not solved the issue.

Any help much appreciated!

Here is my getview. I numbered and added the username to the log tags so I could see which one is being called to determine that the tag from item 1 was being used for item 7, etc:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.availablebutton = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.availablebutton);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }



        final HashMap<String,String> item = (HashMap<String,String> ) items.get(position);
        if (item != null)
        {

                if (holder.availablebutton.getTag() != null) {

                    Log.d("AB gettag is not null:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));

                    if (("on").equals(holder.availablebutton.getTag().toString())) {
                        holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on1);
                        Log.d("tag 1:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                        }
                    else {
                        holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off1);
                        Log.d("tag 2:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                    }

                    } else {

                        if ("2".equals(item.get(TAG_AVAILABLE))) {
                            holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on1);
                            holder.name.setTag("on");
                            Log.d("tag 3:", holder.name.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                            }
                        else {
                            holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off1);
                            holder.name.setTag("off");
                            Log.d("tag 4:", holder.name.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                        }

                       }



            holder.availablebutton.setOnTouchListener(
                    new View.OnTouchListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (holder.availablebutton.getTag() != null) {

                            if (("on").equals(holder.availablebutton.getTag().toString())) {
                                holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off1);
                                holder.availablebutton.setTag("off");
                                Log.d("button pressed 1:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                                }
                            else {
                                holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on1);
                                holder.availablebutton.setTag("on");
                                Log.d("button pressed 2:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                            }

                    } else {

                        if (("on").equals(holder.name.getTag().toString())) {
                            holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off1);
                            holder.availablebutton.setTag("off");
                            Log.d("button pressed 3:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                            }
                        else {
                            holder.availablebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on1);
                            holder.availablebutton.setTag("on");
                            Log.d("button pressed 4:", holder.availablebutton.getTag() + item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                        }

                    }

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                );

        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

here is my logcat, I hope it makes sense:

First time it loads:

```
07-22 23:41:00.948: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser1
07-22 23:41:00.958: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser2
07-22 23:41:00.968: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser3
07-22 23:41:00.978: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser4
```

Pressing the button for user 1:

```
07-22 23:41:09.148: D/button pressed 4:(27178): onUser1
```

Scrolling down after button press:

```
07-22 23:41:15.438: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser5
07-22 23:41:15.488: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser6
07-22 23:41:15.518: D/AB gettag is not null:(27178): onUser7
07-22 23:41:15.518: D/tag 1:(27178): onUser7
07-22 23:41:15.548: D/tag 4:(27178): offUser8
```

Comment: In listview With ViewHolder pattern same views are returned as convertview..for your purpose you need to maintain sparseBooleanArray with clicked item position and its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hold that value in Tag only. When views are recycled it means that when view went off while scrolling, exactly the same view will come in on the list view. This is why convertView is used in getView method. You can fill this recycled view with new data and it looks good but your tag is still the same.
Even when you wouldn't recycle the views (always inflate one without using convertView) - it still won't work because your tags will be simply garbage collected.

What you have to to is for example: make an external hashset where you keep all ids which are ON. In getView method you can check if your id is in hashset and do what you want to do with it.

Also when the only case you need is ON/OFF for your list items - CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE would be a good choice. You would have to read some more about it [START HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29).